# Why do C++ and Java both use the notion of "reference" but not in the same sense?

Tags: java, c++, pointers, reference

In C++ a reference argument to a function allows the function to make the reference refer to something else:

```
int replacement = 23;

void changeNumberReference(int& reference) {
    reference = replacement;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << "i=" << i << "\n"; // i = 1;
    changeNumberReference(i);
    std::cout << "i=" << i << "\n"; // i = 23;
}
```

Analogously, a constant reference argument to a function will throw a compile time error if we try to change the reference:

```
void changeNumberReference(const int& reference) {
    reference = replacement; // compile-time error: assignment of read-only reference 'reference'
}
```

Now, with Java, the docs say that functions arguments of non-primitive types are references. Example from the official docs:

```
public void moveCircle(Circle circle, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
    // code to move origin of circle to x+deltaX, y+deltaY
    circle.setX(circle.getX() + deltaX);
    circle.setY(circle.getY() + deltaY);

    // code to assign a new reference to circle
    circle = new Circle(0, 0);
}
```

> Then circle is assigned a reference to a new Circle object with x = y
>   = 0. This reassignment has no permanence, however, because the reference was passed in by value and cannot change.

To me this doesn't look at all like C++ references. It doesn't resemble regular C++ references because you cannot make it refer to something else, and it doesn't resemble C++ const references because in Java, the code that would change (but really doesn't) the reference does not throw a compile-time error.

This is more similar in behavior to C++ pointers. You can use it to change the pointed objects values, but you cannot changes the pointer's value itself in a function. Also, as with C++ pointers (but not with C++ references), in Java you can pass "null" as value for such an argument.

So my question is: Why does Java use the notion of "reference"? Is it to be understood that they don't resemble C++ references? Or do they indeed really resemble C++ references and I'm missing something?

Comment: Note that in your first C++ example, you are not making the reference "point to something else". Instead, you are changing the value of variable the reference points to. This is conceptually similar to mutating the state of object that is referred to with Java reference,

Comment: @Xion yep, now that I've read your comment I see what you mean and agree with 98% of what you say :) The problem in Java is that you must have access to any and all state of the object in order to conceptually achieve what C++ simply does by letting you set the reference to the value of some other reference.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Why? Because, although consistent terminology is generally good for the entire profession, language designers don't always respect the language use of other language designers, particularly if those other languages are perceived as competitors.

But really, neither use of 'reference' was a very good choice. "References" in C++ are simply a language construct to introduce *aliases* (alternative names for exactly the same entity) explicitly. Things would have been much clearer of they had simply called the new feature "aliases" in the first place. However, at that time the big difficulty was to make everyone understand the difference between pointers (which require dereferencing) and references (which don't), so the important thing was that it was called something other than "pointer", and not so much specifically what term to use.

Java doesn't have pointers, and is proud of it, so using "pointer" as a term was no option. However, the "references" that it does have behave quite a bit as C++'s pointers do when you pass them around - the big difference is that you can't do the nastier low-level operations (casting, adding...) on them, but they result in exactly the same semantics when you pass around handles to entities that are identical vs. entities that merely happen to be equal. Unfortunately, the term "pointer" carries so many negative low-level associations that it's unlikely ever to be accepted by the Java community.

The result is that both languages use the same vague term for two rather different things, both of which might profit from a more specific name, but neither of which is likely to be replaced any time soon. Natural language, too, can be frustrating sometimes!

Comment: Thanks, thinking of C++ references as "aliases" (for the same value/instance) and Java references as "pointers without the nastier low-level operations (casting, adding...)" really clarifies things for me.

Comment: From the name it would sound much more logical to dereference a reference than to dereference something that isn't a reference. :p

Comment: "Competition" in computer science is probably the biggest hurdle to scientific development. _References_? I've worked in both academic and big company development and it's always been like that..

Comment: _Java doesn't have pointers, and is proud of it, so using "pointer" as a term was no option._ What about `NullPointerException` or the fact that the JLS uses the term "pointer"?

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: `NullPointerException` isn't a pointer, but it is an exception indicating that, at a lower level, a NULL pointer was passed/dereferenced. Using `Pointer` as part of an exception, if anything, adds to the nasty image they have.The JLS _has_ to mention pointers, because Java's VM was mainly written in a language that uses them. You can't accurately describe the language specs without describing how the internals work

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: Java uses pointers all over the place; heap objects are referenced through something that for all practical purposes is a pointer.  It's just that Java doesn't expose any operations on pointer types to the programmer.

Comment: I prefer the term "object ID" for Java/.NET references.  At the bit level, such things may typically be implemented as something resembling a pointer, but nothing requires them to be.  What's important is that an object ID contains whatever sort of information the framework/vm needs to identify an object.

Comment: @Kilan "but they result in exactly the same semantics when you pass around handles to **entities that are identical vs. entities that merely happen to be equal**"---Can you please clarify what you meant by this?

Comment: Briefly, when two distinct objects a and b have the same attributes, and you pass around a pointer to a, e.g. to a subroutine, then it can change a but not b. If they are identical, then both a and b can change, and always in the same way, since the values are actually stored in the same place in memory.

Comment: Isn't "Handle" the correct term for Java references? A handle can be reassigned but not share no other pointer properties.

Comment: @user877329: Java references behave a bit like handles, but most kinds of handles would have some kind of human-readable representation which can guarantee that two human-readable handles will compare equal if they represent the same logic, and unequal if they represent different objects with overlapping lifetimes.  Many Java implementations don't keep enough information to support such semantics for objects.  Given full memory snapshots at two distinct times t1 and t2, it may be impossible to determine whether a given reference identified the same object at t1 as it identifies at t2.

Answer (score 10):

A reference is a thing that refers to another thing. Various languages have ascribed a more specific meaning to the word “reference”, usually to “some thing like a pointer without all the bad aspects”. C++ ascribes a specific meaning, as do Java or Perl.

In C++, references are more like aliases (which can be implemented via a pointer). This allows [*pass by reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference#Call_by_reference) or *out arguments*.

In Java, references are pointers except that this isn't a reified concept of the language: All objects are references, primitive types like numbers are not. They don't want to say “pointer” because there is no pointer arithmetic and there are no reified pointers in Java, but they want to make clear that when you pass an `Object` as an argument, the object is *not copied*. This also isn't *pass by reference*, but something more like *pass by sharing*.

Answer (score 7):

It largely goes back to Algol 68, and partly to a reaction against the way C defines pointers.

Algol 68 defined a concept called a reference. It was pretty much the same as (for one example) a pointer in Pascal. It was a cell that contained either NIL or the address of some other cell of some specified type. You could assign to a reference, so a reference could refer to one cell at one time, and a different cell after being reassigned. It did *not*, however, support anything analogous to C or C++ pointer arithmetic.

At least as Algol 68 defined things, however, references were are fairly clean concept that were fairly clumsy to use in practice. Most variable definitions were actually of references, so they defined a shorthand notation to keep it from getting completely out of hand, but any more than trivial use could get clumsy pretty quickly anyway.

For example, a declaration like `INT j := 7;` was really treated by the compiler as a declaration like `REF INT j = NEW LOC INT := 7`. So, what you declared in Algol 68 was normally a reference, which was then initialized to refer to something that was allocated on the heap, and *that* was (optionally) initialized to contain some specified value. Unlike Java, however, they at least tried to let you maintain sane syntax for that instead of constantly having things like `foo bar = new foo();` or trying to tell fibs about "our pointers aren't pointers."

Pascal and most of its descendants (both direct and...spiritual) renamed the Algol 68 reference concept to "pointer" but kept the concept itself essentially the same: a pointer was a variable that held either `nil`, or the address of something you allocated on the heap (i.e., at least as originally defined by Jensen and Wirth, there was no "address-of" operator, so there was no way for a pointer to refer to a normally defined variable). Despite being "pointers", no pointer arithmetic was supported.

C and C++ added a few twists to that. First, they *do* have an address-of operator, so a pointer can refer not only to something allocated on the heap, but to any variable, regardless of how it's allocated. Second, they define arithmetic on pointers--and define array subscripts as basically just a shorthand notation for pointer arithmetic, so pointer arithmetic is ubiquitous (next to unavoidable) in most C and C++.

When Java was being invented, Sun apparently thought "Java doesn't have pointers" was a simpler, cleaner marketing message than: "nearly everything in Java is a pointer, but these pointers are mostly like Pascal's instead of C's." Since they'd decided "pointer" wasn't an acceptable term, they needed something else, and dredged up "reference" instead, even though their references were subtly (and in some cases not so subtly) different from Algol 68 references.

Though it came out somewhat differently, C++ was stuck with roughly the same problem: the word "pointer" was already known and understood, so they needed a different word for this different thing they were adding that referred to something else, but was otherwise quite a bit different from what people understood "pointer" to mean. So, even though it's also noticeably different from an Algol 68 reference, they re-used the term "reference" as well.

Comment: What makes reference in Algol 68 particularly painful is the automatic dereferencing.  That's something convenient as long as it is limited to one level.  But the fact that it could be done several times combined with the syntactic sugar which hided some of the references to the unaware eyes made it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Notion of 'reference type' is a generic one, it can express both a pointer and a reference (in terms of C++), as opposed to 'value type'.
Java's references are really pointers without syntactic overhead of `->` an `*` dereferencing.
If you look into JVM's implementation in C++, they're really bare pointers.
Also, C# has a notion of references similar to Java's, but it also has pointers and 'ref' qualifiers on function parameters, allowing to pass value-types by reference and avoid copying just like `&` in C++.

Comment: how is this answer different / better from earlier answers here?